# messagebox dialog in webapp and The use of Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);

Tags: asp.net

i am The use of following code:

```
      protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(GetType(),"message","ok");
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }
```

Why are not shown the message ?

Please show me the right way

Answer (score 2):

`Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement` adds a piece of javascript on your page. This javascript is not executed directly. It is executed when your page is submitted.

`Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)` is executed direcly and will send the client to the new page before the javascript is executed.

You should probably register your javascript in `Page_Load` instead of in the `Button1_Click` event.

See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registeronsubmitstatement.aspx) for more info on `Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement`.

Answer (score 0):

Because of `Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement` expects some script to be invoked. In your case "OK" is not script. Try something like:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this.GetType(), "message", "alert('OK');");
```

Comment: Probably problem somewhere in page lifecycle and registration. Check this post: http://www.dotnetzone.gr/cs/blogs/rousso/archive/2006/12/02/21568.aspx